# How does StackOverflow detect how many upvotes are on an answer/question?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have trouble understanding this. If Stack Overflow can detect whether a user has already upvoted a question, does it have a flag for each and every post in a table, and whether a user has upvoted it.

If not how does it detect if a user is 'spamming' votes then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the schema on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and you can see the Votes table:

```
Votes
-----
Id
PostId
VoteTypeId
UserId
CreationDate
BountyAmount
```

So they just record each post/user/vote type combination as required.

Obviously there's going to be some logic in there to prevent an single user having both an up and down vote on the same post, or that only the question owner can cast a "accepted answer" vote on their answers, and so on.

Comment: This is an incredible amount of data to be stored

Comment: @Liam maybe, but it's the bare minimum, isn't it?

Comment: @Liam Disk space is fairly cheap

Comment: I guess, as the internet expands, and electronics according to Moores law, it will all become smaller, more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will have. However, it would also seem that they cache the score of a question in the post table for performance reasons.

I also believe that this cached value is recalculated periodically.

(Pseudo):

**Vote**

- user_id
- post_id
- amount

**Post**

- id
- score `/* Cached value of SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Vote WHERE post_id = id */`

Comment: Here's another test for push notifications.  Did you get it?

Comment: Certainly did this time :). Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

IN SO database, there is a `Votes` table which contains `PostId`, `UserId`, and `VoteTypeId` columns. VoteTypeId=2 is for UpVotes and 3 is for DownVotes. So I guess you are right that it does have a flag for each and every post.