# I'm not receiving push notifications anymore

Tags: support, status-completed, ios-app

The iOS app does not appear to be sending push notifications to my iPhone 5c running iOS 7.1.1 anymore.

I'm not sure exactly when the notifications stopped showing up, but I do recall rebooting my device at least once over the weekend. There was also a [data center migration](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/87327655099/data-center-failover-may-31st-2014) that took place during the weekend. I don't know if either of those might have caused it.

I've checked my notification settings and everything is enabled.

I've also tried deleting and reinstalling the app, but still no notifications show up. If I wasn't on the latest version already — which I'm pretty sure I was — I most certainly am at this point. The Help view says I'm on version 1.0.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. 1.0.1.73

Comment: Possibly related; noticed while about to re-download when I didn't get my own notifications: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233482/248072

Comment: @mhlester: Is the beta even maintained anymore?

Comment: Supposed to be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231330/best-way-to-upgrade-beta-version-of-ios-app-to-apple-store-version#comment760255_231333

Comment: @mhlester: Ah, OK. Something seems wrong on their end of things then.

Comment: Possibly related to the data center move?

Comment: Here's a test comment to test push notifications.

Comment: @mhlester: [Not this time ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106783/how-does-stackoverflow-detect-how-many-upvotes-are-on-an-answer-question/106784#comment768899_106784).

Comment: I'm getting notifications of all your comments too. Only now.

Comment: @mhlester: *nudge nudge*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct - there was a missing firewall rule on the outgoing service machine used to send push notifications.  That combined with a bad connection string to our database that tracks exceptions means that nobody knew about it.  Horray for the meta bug machine, you guys are at least 1.5x better than our exception logging framework.

Comment: Glad I reported it. I knew something wasn't right when I hadn't received anything for more than a day.

Comment: They seem to be broken again

Comment: I'm not getting notifications with the Android app.

Comment: Is it happening again, or is it just me?

Comment: I'm not getting notifications either with the Android app. This is months after the last comment though.

Comment: @ElliottTangoFoxtrot how about now?

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas Nope, unfortunately not. I did see it on my computer (browser) as usual but I was not notified automatically via the app.

Comment: @ElliottTangoFoxtrot delete the app and reinstall. Logging in again will reregister your device.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas thanks, I just cleared cache and logged in again and it notified me! Many thanks.